# CakePHP Routing issue

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I know this has been discussed before but I didn't see a suitable answer .... just messy hacks. So I'll try.

I have a multi-site (multi-domain) application where I have a CmsPages controller to serve content. I want to set the homepage to be dependent on the domain so each domain can have a different landing page.

In my routes, I've tried about everything to get the hostname to go through as passed or named parameter, from which I can find() the right CMS page ...  but every way I've tried it, DebugKit shows request pass and named as blank.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [custom route classes](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp) to modify the request that is set to the controller.

check if its the right route and append what you need. You just configure the Router::connect() to use the [correct route class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)

You can also make use of the special [[server]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#using-additional-conditions-when-matching-routes) router config that matches `SERVER_NAME`

Comment: yeah, I've read all this, but I don't think it is - or needs to be as complicated as custom route classes. What I'm trying to do is pass the http host from $_SERVER to the cms page controller, but I can't seem to get it, eg:     Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'cms_pages', 'action' => 'view', 'mydomain.net')); - but i can't see mydomain.net in the view action on the cms_pages controller ... it should be the first parameter, shouldn't it?<shrug>

Comment: Up until 2.2 cake had pretty much nothing in regards to multi site / sub domains. Custom route classes are hardly complicted http://codepad.org/4iNqCxk4